# How to display empty_label for non-mandatory fields with django-filter?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I've applied the basic example of django-filters with the following setup:
models.py

```
class Shopper(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)     
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)      
    Gender_CHOICES = (
        ('','---------'),
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
    )
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=Gender_CHOICES, default=None)
        School_CHOICES = (
        ('','---------'),
        (u'1', 'Primary school'),
        (u'2', 'High School'),
        (u'3', 'Apprenticeship'),
        (u'4', 'BsC'),
        (u'5', 'MsC'),
        (u'6', 'MBA'),
        (u'7', 'PhD'),
    )
    HighestSchool = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank = True, choices = School_CHOICES,default=None)
```

views.py:

```
def shopperlist(request):
    f = ShopperFilter(request.GET, queryset=Shopper.objects.all())
    return render(request,'mysapp/emailcampaign.html', {'filter': f})
```

urls.py:

```
   url(r'^emailcampaign/$', views.shopperlist, name='EmailCampaign'),
```

template:

```
{% extends "basewlogout.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
    <form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" />
    </form>

        {% for obj in filter %}
            <li>{{ obj.FirstName }} {{ obj.LastName }} {{ obj.Email }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

       <a href="{% url 'UserLogin' %}"> 
       <p> Return to home page. </p> </a>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
class ShopperForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Shopper
```

The empty choices `('','---------')` were added to make sure django-filters will display it during filtering and let that field unspecified. However, for the non-mandatory `HighestSchool` field it displays twice when using the model in a create scenario with `ModelForm.` I.e. `('','---------')` should not be listed for non-mandatory field. Then the empty_label cannot be selected during filtering...

How can this be solved with having one empty_label listed during the create view and have the possibility to leave both mandatory and non-mandatory fields unspecified during filtering?

Comment: You have `blank=True` on `HighestSchool` so you don't need to add `('','---------')` manually it will be added later on automatically. That is why you are seeing double empty labels.

Comment: That's correct, however, if I remove it there and go to filter then there is no empty option. However, I do want to have empty option in filtering and don't want to specify a certain school option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this within the `__init__` by updating the `empty_label` directly on the filter, thus avoiding the need to redefine *all* options.

```py
class FooFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters["some_choice_field"].extra.update(empty_label="All")

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = [
            "some_choice_field",
        ]
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should not add the blank choice to your choices set. So please remove the following lines:

```
('','---------'),
```

Django will automatically add these when the Field is not required and everything (django models, django forms, django views etc) *except* django-filter will work as expected.

Now, concerning django-filter. What you describe is a common requirement, already present in the issues of the [django-filter project](https://github.com/alex/django-filter). Please take a look here for a possible workaround https://github.com/alex/django-filter/issues/45. I will just copy paste cvk77's code from there for reference:

```
class NicerFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(NicerFilterSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  for name, field in self.filters.iteritems():
    if isinstance(field, ChoiceFilter):
      # Add "Any" entry to choice fields.
      field.extra['choices'] = tuple([("", "Any"), ] + list(field.extra['choices']))`
```

So to use that just extend your filters from NicerFilterSet instead of normal FilterSet.

Also a Q+D solution you could do is the following: Define a global variable in your models.py:

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
  ('Male','Male'),
  ('Female','Female'),
)
```

and use it as expected in your Model.

Now, in your filters.py define another global variable like this:

```
FILTER_GENDER_CHOICES = list(models.FILTER_CHOICES)
FILTER_GENDER_CHOICES.insert(0, ('','---------') )
```

and then define your filter like this:

```
class ShopperFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  gender = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices= FILTER_GENDER_CHOICES ) 
  class Meta:
    model = models.Shopper
```

Comment: Thanks!
I've posted another answer below which works in Python 3 in case anyone is having issues running the cvk777 answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the less experienced, here's a Python3 compatible version of the original work-around by cvk77, which I found in the accepted answer by @Serafeim.

```
class NicerFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(NicerFilterSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  for name, field in self.filters.items():
    if isinstance(field, ChoiceFilter):
      # Add "Any" entry to choice fields.
      field.extra['choices'] = tuple([("", "Any"), ] + list(field.extra['choices']))
```

Changes:

- `self.filters.iteritems()` was changed to `self.filters.items()`
- Remove erroneous backtick (it was present in the github thread too - no fault of @Serafeim)